# Wallaby.js: Test framework [mocha@2.0.1] is not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, intellij-idea

Hi I'm getting an error that mocha is not supported:

```
wallaby.js started
Failed to load configuration file:  Test framework [mocha@2.0.1] is not supported
```

my wallaby.js file:

```
var babel = require('babel');

var es6ToEs5Preprocessor = function(file) {
    return babel.transform(file.content, {sourceMap: true});
};

module.exports = {
    files: [
        "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    tests: [
        "test/**/*.test.js"
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        '**/*.js': es6ToEs5Preprocessor
    },
    env: {
        type: 'node',
        runner: 'node'
    },
    testFramework: 'mocha@2.0.1',
    debug: true
};
```

I have tried running without setting the framework though just getting a different error, mocha ins installed both locally and globally in the correct version

Thanks for any help

Comment: The officially supported mocha version for node.js is 2.1.0 (still  2.0.1 for browsers, though). Have you tried upgrading mocha to this newer version and run it again ? https://github.com/wallabyjs/public#supported-testing-frameworks

Comment: the change has fixed the problem, thanks, next time I have to read the doc more carefully